# jQuery check if partial input is in the array

Tags: jquery

I want to check if part of an input is part of the array. For example: when I enter `apple` and click submit, I want it to return true because that set of characters matches two of the objects in my array {fruit-apple and fruit-pineapple}

However I can't get it to evaluate correctly. What's wrong with my code?

HTML

```
<input type='text' class='fruit'>
<input type='submit' class="submit">
<p></p>
```

jQuery

```
$(".submit").on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  doesFruitAlreadyExist();
});

var fruitsList = "fruit-apple,fruit-oranges,fruit-pineapple";
var fruitsArray = fruitsList.split(",");
var fruitName = fruitsList.substring(fruitsList.indexOf("-") + 0);
console.log("fruit names: " + fruitName);
// console.log(fruitsArray);

function doesFruitAlreadyExist() {
  var fruitInput = $(".fruit").val();

  if (fruitInput) {
      console.log("Does the fruitsArray contain any part of " + fruitInput + " ? : "+ fruitsArray.includes(fruitInput));

    if ($.inArray(fruitInput, fruitsArray) !== -1) {
      $("p").text($.inArray(fruitInput, fruitsArray)); 
      console.log(fruitInput + " appears in fruitsArray");

      fruitsArray.push(fruitInput);
    }

    console.log("Array of fruits: " + fruitsArray);
  } else {
    console.log("Please enter a fruit");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're looking to see if `fruitInput` is contained in your array, you're checking each item for an exact match.

```
if ($.inArray(fruitInput, fruitsArray) !== -1) { // <- matches fruit-apple, not apple
  $("p").text($.inArray(fruitInput, fruitsArray)); 
  console.log(fruitInput + " appears in fruitsArray");

  fruitsArray.push(fruitInput);
}
```

If you want to check to see if a value shows up in your array at least once, the `some()` method should do the trick:

```
if (fruitsArray.some(fruit => fruit.includes(fruitInput))) { 
    // Using an arrow function here, you could use .some(function(fruit) { return 
    // fruit.includes(fruitInput) }), too
    // If .some() returns true above, it was in there!
}
```

`.includes()` isn't supported by older versions of IE, so you could use a `.indexOf()`, too (or a regular expression if you wanted):

```
fruit.indexOf(fruitInput) > -1
```

Need to get the index for a specific reason? `.findIndex()` will work if you don't need to support old versions of IE (otherwise, you could do it in a `for` loop where you increment a counter and return that value on a match).

```
const index = fruitsArray.findIndex(fruit => fruit.includes(fruitInput));
```